# Can "adb remount" be used on a stock phone (unrooted)?

Tags: adb

Is it possible to use `adb remount` with a standard firmware and without having rooted the device? If not, is there another way to force the system to make /system writable without rooting the device?

Comment: I believe this is the purpose of rooting...

Comment: Wait, actually... while I'm installing an app, /system has to be unlocked, right? Because there are .apk files of all installed apps at `/system/apps`...

Comment: No, those are only the system apps.  User apps are stored in `/data/apps/`.

Comment: @MatthewRead: Oh, right.

Comment: even updated versions of '/system' apps don't overwrite their original versions in /system/app

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Without root:** No, for security reasons this command is only accessible for the superuser.
**Standard firmware, rooted:** Yes, if the partition you like to remount is not in a locked flash region (HTC calls that S-on/S-off)

Comment: Thanks. Well, I guess what I was trying to do won't work. :(